# What is the simplest way to copy a record from one entity to another entity with Entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a SQL table that contains records that I want to move over to an almost identical table using Entity Framework. i.e. moving records from main table to an archive table.

The second table is a superset of the original table in that it has a few extra fields to designate archive date, etc...

Is there a simpler way to accomplish this then manually matching each field from the original entity to the archive entity? 
I looked at Automapper but see that it only works with in memory entities and not my data which is Iqueryable.

TIA 
John
(EF newbie)

Comment: Is this something you need to do regularly or a one time deal?

Comment: A five different entities in a single project so it is a one time project.

Comment: Are you wanting to know specifically how to do this with EF? I ask because for a one-time move, a SQL script might be easier to write.

Comment: I want to know specifically how to do this in EF. :)

Comment: @JohnS You need to bring it into memory anyway, so you can still use AutoMapper.

Comment: OK, anyone know of any basic examples? I've searched but am obviously not using the proper search terms because I am returning very little that is of use.

Comment: Ok figured it out. Thanks for the assistance all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to have 2 entity classes (one for the transaction table and one for the archive table) and use the [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to populate the archive object from the transactional object, and call the SaveChanges.

Comment: I do have two entity classes but when I try to map I get an error relating to the fact that the source is of type Iquery. I need to get that into memory and am not sure how to do that. (remember newbie here). TIA

Comment: @JohnS I could not find an easier way to use AutoMapper to map IQueryable, than to convert to in memory lists, and then map. There are some blog posts about writing extension methods on IQueryable to build the expressions, but they deal with selecting and projecting data to disparate entities. Your case looks like an auditing scenario, and I found [this blog post](http://complicatedwords.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/entity-framework-trigger-like-auditing/) which outlines how it can be done. You basically have the Audit / Archive fields in an interface, and set up an event handler on SavingChanges.